# Can't get the IriConverter from the container because it's not public

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com, symfony-dependency-injection

I trying to load the `api_platform.iri_converter` but get an error:

> The \"api_platform.iri_converter\" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.

This is the code:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Security\Authorization\Voter;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

abstract class BaseVoter extends Voter
{
    public ContainerInterface $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Security\Authorization\Voter;

class VenueVoter extends BaseVoter
{
    protected function voteOnAttribute(): bool
    {
        /** @var User $tokenUser */
        $tokenUser = $token->getUser();

        if (self::VENUE_CREATE === $attribute) {
            $iri = $this->container->get('api_platform.iri_converter')->getItemFromIri($valueWithIri);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not inject the Container.

Instead, inject the `IriConverter` directly.

```
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Routing\IriConverterInterface;

abstract class BaseVoter extends Voter
{
    public IriConverterInterface $iriConverter;

    public function __construct(IriConverterInterface $iriConverter)
    {
        $this->iriConverter = $iriConverter;
    }
}
```